# Is it possible to refresh all clients with a new thymeleaf model?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I need the front end to display the most recent record in my db (mysql if it makes a difference). Is there a way for my java app to send that value in the thymeleaf model to all existing sessions?

The only way I can think of is to send an ajax request every second to an endpoint that will respond with whether it needs to update or not but this seems a bit hacky

Comment: Before websockets that *was* the way. Now there's sockets. Less hacky.